# Show that the lower triangular matrix $L=(l_{ij})i,j=1,…,n∈Rn×n$ resulting from Cholesky decomposition has the same band width m as the band matrix A

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

Let $ A=\left(a_{i j}\right)_{i, j=1, \ldots, n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ be a symmetric and positive definite band matrix with band width $ m \in \mathbb{N} $, i.e. $ a_{i j}=0 $ for $ i, j \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ |i-j|>m $.

Show that the lower triangular matrix $ L=\left(l_{i j}\right)_{i, j=1, \ldots, n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ resulting from the Cholesky decomposition has the same band width $ m $.  This means $ l_{i j}=0 $ for $ i, j \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ i-j>m $.

This statement is a theorem from my script on Numerical Linear Algebra 1. I tried a few examples and indeed the band structure of the band matrix A is preserved. But this is a big advantage, because if you write the algorithm for it, you can avoid the places where the zeros are at A with the bandwidth m and you have to calculate less.

To perhaps prove the theorem, one could use induction, but am not sure where that would lead.

Here is also the corresponding algorithm:
[Cholesky decomposition for symmetric positive definite band matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xf1q.png)

I finally found the task in a book with a description of the proof, but unfortunately it makes little sense to me, maybe someone can explain it or has another idea because of that.

[Proof from the mentioned book (in German)](https://books.google.de/books?id=rawaPgVh21EC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=schwarz%20numerische%20mathematik%20cholesky-zerlegung%20bandmatrix&source=bl&ots=XutIuQm2rE&sig=tPW-72V9ersnnU3BaOFPcKfDB4k&hl=de&ei=uiwMS-2pGYWfsAbHx-GkAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=schwarz%20numerische%20mathematik%20cholesky-zerlegung%20bandmatrix&f=false)

**Proof.** It suffices to show that the first reduction step described by

$l_{11} =\sqrt{a_{11}} ; \quad l_{i 1}=\frac{a_{i 1}}{\sqrt{a_{11}}}=\frac{a_{i 1}}{l_{11}}, \quad i=2,3, \ldots, n ; \hspace{1cm} (*)$

$a_{i k}^{(1)} =a_{i k}-\frac{a_{i 1} a_{1 k}}{a_{11}}=a_{i k}-l_{i 1} l_{k 1}, \quad i, k=2,3, \ldots, n \hspace{1cm} (**)$

in the first column of $ \boldsymbol{L} $ below the diagonal (1) produces nonzero elements only in the $ m $ side diagonals, and (2) that the reduced matrix $ \boldsymbol{A}^{(1)}=\left(a_{i k}^{(1)}\right) $ has the same width $ m $.

(1) Assertion: is true because of $(*)$, since it is $ l_{i 1}=0 $ for all $ i $ with $ i-1>m $, since then by premise $ a_{i 1}=0 $.

(2) Assertion: for symmetry reasons one needs only elements ( a_{i k}^{(1)} ) below the diagonal. For any place $ (i, k) $ with $ i \geq k \geq 2 $ and $ i-k>m $, on the one hand, according to the premise $ a_{i k}=0 $ and, on the other hand, due to the statement just made $ l_{i 1}=0 $, because it is $ i-1>i-k>m $.

Thus, because of $(**)$ in fact $ a_{i k}^{(1)}=0 $ holds for all $ i, k \geq 2 $ with $|i-k|>m $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetric positive definite with upper and lower bandwidth $m$. Partition the matrix $A$ and the Cholesky factor as $2$-by-$2$ block matrices where the upper left corners are $1$-by-$1$ matrices, and the lower right corners are square matrices of dimension $(n-1)$, i.e.,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & u^T \\ u & A_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} l & 0 \\ v & L_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} l & v^T \\ 0 & L_{22}^T \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} l^2 & l v^T \\ vl & L_{22}L_{22}^T + vv^T\end{bmatrix}$$
Only the first $m$ components of the column vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ can be non-zero because $A$ has lower bandwidth $m$. It follows that $$v = u/l$$ has the same property. The Schur complement matrix $$S_{22} = L_{22} L_{22}^T = A_{22} - vv^T$$ is banded with upper and lower bandwidth $m$, because $A_{22}$ has this property and the entries of $vv^T$ are zero outside of the upper-left $m$-by-$m$ corner.

---

This shows how to reduce the dimension of the active matrix by one while preserving the upper bound on the half-bandwidth. A rigorous proof would apply the well-ordering principle rather than the principle of mathematical induction.